# How to change OpenCV Android version

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv

I am currently building my android project with OpenCV 2.4.9  But I would like to update my resources to begin building with OpenCV 3.0.0.  I am not sure how to change what I am currently using.  When I follow the steps as I did to import OpenCV originally, the module does not show up in the project window on the left of the screen (I am using Android Studio).  Also, after importing the module I get an error that "failed to find target with hash string 'android-14'.  I am currently building against SDK 22.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had not downloaded SDK build 14 which was what OpenCV had been set to build against.  I was able to fix this by downloading build 14 in the SDK manager.